# Cual es el error?

Tags: javascript

No me cambia de color el documento

```js
function changeme() {
  
  var color = "#";
  var letras = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  function random() {
  for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
   
   color += letras[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);
   
  }
  
  return color;
  }
  
  function setcolor() {
   
   document.getElementById("changeme").setAttribute("style", "color:" random(););
   
  }
  return random();
  
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="learn.js"></script>
  <style>
    #forEach {width: 300px; height: 100px; background-color: red; position: relative;}
 #forClasico {width: 300px; height: 100px; background-color: blue; position: relative;}
 #forin {width: 300px; height: 100px; background-color: green; position: relative;}
 #changeme {width: 300px; height: 100px; background-color: green; position: relative;}
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--  <div id="forEach">
        <h4 style="text-align:center;">Simplex forEach LOOP(array start w/ 1)</h4>
  
    </div>
 <div id="forClasico">
        <h4 style="text-align:center;">Simplex for LOOP(1 - 10)</h4>
  
    </div>
 <div id="forin">
        <h4 style="text-align:center;">Simplex forin(at the moment in array)</h4>
    </div>--->
 <div id="changeme" onclick="changeme()">
        <h4 style="text-align:center;">Changing the bgcolor(click to change for random color);</h4>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tienes un `;` de más aquí: `random(););` Tienes que quitar el primero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparte de los errores de compilacion tambien te falto llamar al metodo `setcolor`, en el codigo javascript solo devuelves la funcion `random`.
Antes de `return` deberias llamar al metodo `setcolor()`
Tambien veo errores en la funcion `setcolor`
te sugiero este codigo para javascript

```
function changeme() {
var color = "#";
var letras = "0123456789ABCDEF";
function random() {
    for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
        color += letras[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function setcolor() {
    document.getElementById("changeme").style.color = random();
}
setcolor();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenias dos problemas de compilacion:
el `;` en `random(););` y te falto cerrar `]` en `letras[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);`

```js
function changeme() {

    var color = "#";
    var letras = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    function random() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letras[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }

        return color;
    }

    function setcolor() {
        document.getElementById("changeme").setAttribute("style", "color:" + random());
    }
    return random();
}

console.log(changeme());
```

Comment: Hola @DanielPerez, gracias por tu respuesta y participar en el foro. Sin embargo, para este tipo de preguntas (error tipográfico) es mejor dejar un comentario en vez de una respuesta ya que la pregunta será cerrada en pocos minutos ya que no es un error que le pueda servir a futuros lectores. Un saludo! :)

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme a comprender mejor el sitio y un saludo :)